# Can we implement data lineage on queries run via Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Could anyone help me in providing some pointers on how do we implement Data lineage on a DW type solution built on Google BigQuery using Google Cloud storage as source and Google Cloud Composer as the workflow manager to implement a series of SQL's?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in Cloud Storage, you would maybe like to use something like [GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#googlecloudstoragetobigqueryoperator) to first load your data in Bigquery, then use [BigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#bigqueryoperator) to run your queries.

Then you could see how your different DAGs,tasks etc are running in the Airflow [Web UI inside Composer.](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface)